# Django with mysql installation module mac ox

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, pymysql

I would like to use mysql in a Django project, but I alway have module problems on my mac.

I have two kinds of problems :/

First:
I use brew mysql, so I have my sql on my laptop. I try to create a database with mysql command but I couldn't connect correctly my database to my django project. 
I follow this protocole from that blog: 
http://blog.joefallon.net/2013/10/install-mysql-on-mac-osx-using-homebrew/

I use : mysql_secure_installation
when I do:
 manage.py run server

I have :

```
/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'mynameuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

So I follow 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm
.It's about creating a mysql file to after have the good property ('user','password' etc) to open it

When I try to create a database I couldn't import :
pymysql
MySQLdb

Have you got any solutions for using Django and MySQL with python ?

Is there a Transportable Solution for mac and window ?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To run a sql database, it's possible to use the MySQLdb library.

Before running any django code, you will need to do this:

in the manage.py file :

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```